# if folders exist - by using wildcard

Tags: bash, shell

### or *"How to handle prefixed folder names?"*

Inside a folder I have two (or more) `foo_*` folders

> foo_0
>   foo_1

**What I'm trying to achieve** is to

- perform an action **if**  there's 1 or more `foo_*` folders
- Use a wildcard `*`

**Currently I'm doing** it this way (going directly to check if directory `foo_0` exists):

```
prefix=foo_

if [ -d "./${prefix}0/" ]; then
  printf "foo_0 folder found!"
  # delete all foo_* folders
fi
```

Having directories `0`-to-*`N`* so the above works, but i'm not sure I'll always have a `foo_0` folder...

**I'd like to do use a wildcard**:

```
prefix=foo_

if [ -d "./${prefix}*/" ]; then                 # By using wildcard...
  printf "One or more foo_* folders found!"     # this never prints
  # delete all foo_* folders
fi
```

I've read that a wildcard `*` inside quotes loses its powers, but placing it outside quotes throws :

```
if [ -d "./${prefix}"* ]  <<< ERROR: binary operator expected
```

Or is it possible to use some sort of **regex** like? `./foo_\d+` ?

---

The **only solution** I don't (*arguably*) like, is by using `set`

```
set -- foo_*
if [ -d $1 ]; then
  printf "foo_* found!"
fi
```

but it wipes program arguments.
Is there any other **nice solution** to this I'm missing?

Comment: Using **find** command is allowed?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu I already tried some sort of `find . -type d -name "${prefix}*"` - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a **nice solution** for pretty much all such cases is to use `ls` in the test, in that it often works quite simply:

`if [ -n "$(ls -d foo_*)" ]; then ...` If you want to do more regexp-like matching you can `shopt -s extglob` and then match with `ls foo_+([0-9])`.

There's also an all-bash solution using several shell options, but it's not as easy to remember, so I'll leave that to another poster ;-)

EDIT: As @PesaThe pointed out, using `ls foo_*` would fail if there's only one empty matching directory, as just the empty contents of that directory would get listed and `ls foo_*` would not only match directories, so it's preferable to use `-d`.

Comment: my bad, it should have been `if [ -n "$(ls foo_*)" ];then printf "One or more foo_* folders found!";fi`, as it tests if the output of `ls` is non-empty.

Comment: It won't fail if the directories are empty and also won't fail if there are no matches, although it will produce a warning when there are no matches, which can be turned off with `ls foo_* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @PesaThe You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer.

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee Could you elaborate how using `ls` here will cause problems with weird filenames? Isn't it just like parsing parts of an HTML file, where it's usually a bad idea to use a regexp, but where there are also some use cases where the frowned upon approach will produce much cleaner and easier code?

Comment: I agree that it's probably merely unnecessary here. I tried to think of a scenario where you would want to see the number of matches separately from the action of operating on the matches, but it seems like a rather esoteric corner case. And if you are looping over a wildcard anyway, just `test -e "$file" || continue` at the top of the loop.